# Firestore v9 Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, compiler-errors

I tried to add new users from the signup page to firestore but it didn't work.

Here's my **config.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = initializeApp ({
  //cred
});

export const auth = getAuth(firebaseConfig)
export const database = getDatabase(firebaseConfig);
```

And **Signup.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import  firebase  from "./config";
import { collection, addDoc,doc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

class Signup extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '-',
            email: '-',
        };
    }

    addUser = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const collectionRef = doc(database, 'users');
            const docRef = addDoc(collectionRef, {
                name: this.state.name,
                email: this.state.email,
            });
          } catch (e) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
          }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
              //do something
              <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addUser}>Submit</button>
            </div>
    )}
}
```

And here's the error:

> FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

I changed **Config.js** to:

```
export const auth = getAuth()
export const database = getDatabase();
```

and I still got the same error.
Does it mean that I didn't connect firestore successfully? :'(
Please help me solve this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const collectionRef = doc(database, 'users');
```

The `database` here is an instance of realtime database and not Firestore.

```
export const database = getFirestore(); // not getDatabase()
```

You must use `getFirestore()` to get an instance of Firestore and pass it in `doc()`.
The error says `Expected first argument to collection()` even if an invalid argument is passed to `doc()`.

Comment: I had created a [PR](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/pull/5437) to change the error message for `doc()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the path for the collection

`const collectionRef = doc(database, '/users');`

it worked with me!