# Firebase 9 + NextJS 12 - Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, nosql

I'm trying to create a simple Query to Firestore database in my NextJS application.

I have `clientApp.ts` which looks like this:

```
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
// const storage = getStorage();
// const analytics = getAnalytics(firebase);

export { firebaseApp, db };
```

And then I have some index.js file where I have single method:

```
    import { collection, query, where, getDocs, getDoc, onSnapshot, doc, limit } from 'firebase/firestore';
    import { db } from '../firebase/clientApp';

    export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
      try {
        const videoRef = collection(db, 'videos');
        const q = query(videoRef, limit(8));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
        });
        return { props: { x: [] } };
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return { props: { x: [] } };
      }
    };
```

It will end up in `catch` block with error:

```
FirestoreError [FirebaseError]: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore
    at collection (file:///C:/Develop/petrolhat-nextjs/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.mjs:19949:19)
    at getServerSideProps (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:108:88)
    at Object.renderToHTML (C:\Develop\petrolhat-nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:479:26)
    at async doRender (C:\Develop\petrolhat-nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:1389:38)
    at async C:\Develop\petrolhat-nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:1484:28
    at async C:\Develop\petrolhat-nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\server\response-cache.js:63:36 {
  code: 'invalid-argument',
  toString: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

If I console.log(db) right before it is used it return:

```
Firestore {
  _credentials: FirebaseCredentialsProvider {
    authProvider: Provider {
      name: 'auth-internal',
      container: [ComponentContainer],
      component: [Component],
      instances: Map(0) {},
      instancesDeferred: Map(0) {},
      instancesOptions: Map(0) {},
      onInitCallbacks: Map(0) {}
...
```

So it seems to me DB is set correctly. So I tried to google a lot and find a possible solution, I also check for these topics here in StackOverflow but nothing helped:

1. [Firebase is expecting the first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69814265/firebase-is-expecting-the-first-argument-to-collection-to-be-a-collectionrefer)
2. [Firestore v9 Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69166454/firestore-v9-expected-first-argument-to-collection-to-be-a-collectionreference)
3. [V 9 FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69299570/v-9-firebaseerror-expected-first-argument-to-collection-to-be-a-collectionref)

So if anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong it will be great!

Comment: I encountered a similar thread recently and I found [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5216) inside the Firebase JS SDK repo. It explains that exporting a Firebase created instance and importing it into another package could fail with the same error due to how Firebase validates the instance. You could test if this is the case since it seems similar to your code. An alternative could be to only export the configuration details like [this example](https://github.com/firebase/codelab-friendlychat-web/blob/main/web/src/firebase-config.js) web-app does.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing! Currently working around it by sticking with firebase v8 but that's obviously not a long-term solution... Did you have any luck?

Comment: I fixed my issue, root cause was that `getServerSideProps` is never executed on the client and because of that it can not use client firebase library :)

Comment: @Andurit so what did you do? used the Firebase Admin SDK?

Comment: @RomShiri I use Client SDK for client requests and AdminSDK for server requests