# NextJS Server not able to use firestore

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have some functions I need to run on both the front and backend of a nextjs server. I am trying to use firebase on the server side to deal with some sensitive data, but I am not able to make a docref to the firestore collection doc. I keep getting the following error:
[image: firestore error]
but I have printed out the offending value and it is a valid. Below is the code:

```
//page/api/firestore
import { doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "lib/firestore";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    const docRef = doc(db, "bots", "access_code");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  res.status(200).json({});
}
```

and the db value is defined below:

```
//lib/firestore
export default initializeApp({
  apiKey: "**********",
  authDomain: "**********",
  projectId: "**********",
  storageBucket: "**********",
  messagingSenderId: "**********",
  appId: "**********",
});

export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

I am doing the exact some thing on the frontend and it works fine

Comment: Can you console.log(db) in the server side code and check whether it is defined?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, it is defined!

Comment: Have you gone through the [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69826971/firebase-9-nextjs-12-expected-first-argument-to-collection-to-be-a-collect)?. Seems in your case also docRef is not executed on the client

Comment: `pages/api/firestore` is an API route, and gets executed on the server.

Comment: @juliomalves that was the issue, thanks! i didn't realize that pages in the API folder use nodejs, not web version 9

Comment: @SeyiOluwaleimu can you post your solution as an answer to the question?. It will help the community when someone comes across the same situation.

Comment: @Badala Prashanth I just did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! NextJS uses NodeJS in the api directory, but I was using the firebase Web 9 SDK for both the front and backend. Once I switched to the Node SDK for the api files everything worked fine!!!

Comment: Can you please explaing more bud since I am in the similar situation with firebase