# How can I access firebase FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am trying to use Firebase in a Next.Js project but I keep getting this error with Firebase 9.8

**firebase.js**

```js
import { getApp, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore/lite";

const firebaseConfig = {
  Some config details
};

function createFirebaseApp(config) {
  try {
    return getApp();
  } catch {
    return initializeApp(config);
  }
}

const app = createFirebaseApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export default db;
```

and the page where I'm trying to load this is the following

```js
import { getSession} from "next-auth/react";
import React from "react";
import db from "../../firebase";
import { collection, doc, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore/lite";

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

  const session = await getSession(context);

  if (!session) {
    return {
      props: {},
    };
  }

  const docRef = collection(db, `users/${session.user.email}/orders`);

  getDocs(docRef)
    .then((snapshot) => {
      let user = [];
      snapshot.docs.forEach((sdoc) => {
        user.push({ ...sdoc.data(), id: sdoc.id });
      });
      console.log(user);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

I get this error

```
[FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore] {
  code: 'invalid-argument',
  customData: undefined,
  toString: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

I have also tried simply getting users

```js
collection(db, 'users');
```

Using the older firebase it should be

```js
  const firebaseOrders = await db
      .collection("users")
      .doc(session.user.email)
      .collection("orders")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc");
```

How can I access this with the orderby and nested collections. The Firebase docs don't seem to cover this.

if I log the db object I get this with the config details

```
Firestore {
  _authCredentials: LiteAuthCredentialsProvider { auth: null },
  _appCheckCredentials: LiteAppCheckTokenProvider {
    appCheckProvider: Provider {
      name: 'app-check-internal',
      container: [ComponentContainer],
      component: null,
      instances: Map(0) {},
      authDomain: ,
      projectId: ,
      storageBucket: ,
      messagingSenderId: ,
      appId: ,
      measurementId: 
    },
    _config: { name: '[DEFAULT]', automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false },
    _name: '[DEFAULT]',
    _automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false,
    _container: ComponentContainer { name: '[DEFAULT]', providers: [Map] }
  },
  _databaseId: DatabaseId { projectId: '', database: '(default)' }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `db`?  We can't see how it's define.  Please edit the question to show enough code that anyone can use to reproduce the error.

Comment: It seems you are trying to fetch multiple documents using `getDocs()`. You should be using a collection reference like this: `const colRef = collection(db, `users/${session.user.email}/orders`);` instead of the docRef

Comment: @DougStevenson the db it's a reference to the firestore is defined in the first firebase.js

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes there are multiple documents in the orders. but I get the same error while using collection()

Comment: Please edit the question to show enough code that anyone can use to reproduce the error.  This includes where `db` comes from, since we can't see that right now.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have updated the whole code but I think you can see it is exporting from my firebase config code at top. you can see the import statement

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(db)` right before the `collection()` statement? Can you share the output of that? Also are you sure the error is thrown by that code shared?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes I did you can see that in the updated code

Comment: can you console.log this `users/${session.user.email}/orders`; or console.log(docRef) this const docRef = collection(db, `users/${session.user.email}/orders`)

Comment: @Ingenious_Hans it returned the collection reference once Although rerunning the code it doesn't return instead there is an error

Comment: Hi, could you please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69826971/firebase-9-nextjs-12-expected-first-argument-to-collection-to-be-a-collect#comment124631144_69826971) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem, in my case i was importing `firebase/firestore/lite`

Try to remove `lite`